# Как текст из label в Dialog отправить в label MainWindow?

Tags: qt, qtcreator

Есть два окна MainWindow и Dialog. По нажатию на кнопку открывается диалоговое окнов котором есть кнопка и текст в label. Нужно что бы по нажатию на кнопку текст из label в Dialog отобразился в label из MainWindow

// mainwindow.cpp

```
#include "mainwindow.h"
#include "ui_mainwindow.h"

MainWindow::MainWindow(QWidget *parent) :
    QMainWindow(parent),
    ui(new Ui::MainWindow)
{
    ui->setupUi(this);
}

MainWindow::~MainWindow()
{
    delete ui;
}

void MainWindow::on_newDialog_clicked()
{
    Dialog window;
    window.setModal(true);
    window.exec();
}
```

// dialog.cpp

```
#include "dialog.h"
#include "ui_dialog.h"

Dialog::Dialog(QWidget *parent) :
    QDialog(parent),
    ui(new Ui::Dialog)
{
    ui->setupUi(this);
}

Dialog::~Dialog()
{
    delete ui;
}

void Dialog::on_sendText_clicked()
{

}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
void MainWindow::on_newDialog_clicked()
{
    Dialog window;
    window.setModal(true);

    connect(&window, &Dialog::labelText, [&](QString text) {
        ui->label->setText(text);
    });

    window.exec();
}
```

Dialog.h

```
class Dialog{
//... 
signals:
    void labelText(QString text);
}
```

Dialog.h

```
void Dialog::on_sendText_clicked() 
{
    emit labelText(ui->label->text());
}
```